# Alternative to manually registering objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
NetworkCode network = new NetworkCode();

OpponentTeam opponentTeam = new OpponentTeam();

OpponentDoAbilityState opponentDoAbility = new OpponentDoAbilityState();

// register network methods
RegisterNetworkMethods(network, opponentTeam);
RegisterNetworkMethods(network, opponentDoAbility);
```

In the above code I have 1 instance of NetworkCode and then 2 instances of other objects (this could be 100 instances of different objects I use). Inside these classes can be methods that have a certain attribute on them. The `RegisterNetworkMethods()` is looking for methods with that attribute and then it creates and stores a delegate for that instance method to be called at a later time.

My question is, do I have to manually call some kind of `RegisterNetworkMethods()` like this on all the objects that I care about? It seems tedious and easy for me to miss calling this on a given object. In the same breath, I don't want every object to require NetworkCode object in its constructor as I don't want to leak that into all these classes. Is there any other way to get all object instances created and/or have some hook that is called when an object is created so I can call `RegisterNetworkMethods()` inside that hook? Just looking for a more convenient way to handle this.

Comment: why dont you just use an interface for all your "callable types" and then just keep a collection or dictionary and choose and call the appropriate one?  Or maybe use type composition like MEF.  or use the constructor and setup dependency injection. There are many things you can do but we need more information on what exactly you are trying to achieve and possibly more code.

Comment: I don't want to use a constructor because I don't want to leak my Network class into all these other classes.So within any of these objects,I want to be able to define a method that will be called for a given network message.When I get the network message it calls all object methods that were assigned to that msg.Each network message also has it's own argument type.Right now I put a custom attribute on any methods which has a parameter which is the network message.It's the least invasive way to the classes.I have to manually call register on every object to hook this all up which I dislike.

Comment: I think interfaces would give me similar functionality. If I had 1 interface for every message that has 1 method to implement for that network message it would work all the same. But as noted I still have to "register" (ie add them to a list) manually. Was just wondering if there was some other way to basically get them added to the list without leaking the Network class (which has the list) into them or manually have a massive amount of lines of every class registration. Some kind of hook perhaps that .NET calls whenever ANY object is created or something like that.

Comment: Right now... What you are doing seems to me like an anti pattern... You should use interfaces and MEF or dependency injection... That way you would never have to worry about "registering" the instances... As long as they implement the interface or attribute they would be "registered" automatically.

Comment: Also I do not understand why do you have to "register" a delegate to be called later on?   If you use MEF you can search for all classes that implement a certain interface at the beginning of your software and instantiate them put them in a dictionary or list that you can later on search.  I do this all the time.

Comment: Putting the instances in a dictionary/list is what I'm calling "registering". So it's basically the same end game there. I want full control of the instantiation of these objects as there are other things I hook up in them so their creations and setting up can be more complex than just finding all class with an interface and instantiating them on startup.

Comment: It is not the same because now you have to explicitly register them... If you use MEF you will write code that will look through your assembly or assemblies and find the classes that implement the interfaces... you do this once at startup... so if you add new classes for example you would not need to do anything for them to get picked up

Comment: Once again you are describing an anti-pattern... precisely because you are not using inversion of control pattern your dependencies are giving you extensibility and maintainability problems... You need to rethink your architecture to use Inversion of Control and/or type composition.

Comment: Another idea would be to have a Base Class with the ability to register itself and derive from it.   What does the software do? what is the ultimate goal? Maybe if you explain more about the actual functionality we could think of something else.

Comment: It's a video game (I thought the example code was showing that, sorry). IOC still creates dependency issues as your classes are now dependent on an interface. IOC is ideal over newing up inside your classes, but I'm not newing up anything inside my classes currently so if anything my issue isn't a dependancy issue and IOC would create more of a dependancy issue than I have now which is why I'd prefer to avoid it.

Comment: My classes are nice and isolated and internally ignorant making them a breeze to test. They fire events to inform the outside world of internal changes and have other objects hook up to their methods to inform them they need to do something. This means the creation of them isn't simply creating the instance and moving on as instances need to be hooked up to communicate with each other to make the game be what it is. I could look into base class to self register. Given unity fires Awake() method on instantiation that might work for this. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: If these are mono behaviors the best way is to just call GetComponent<> or similar to find a reference to the class that handles the "registration", and just have them register themselves on Awake or Start.  Probably Awake would be better. I do this in Unity when for example I have Enemy Waves and I need to account for all enemies on a Level of my game,  So every time an Enemy gets instantiated the enemy just finds my GameState and my LevelController and registers itself.

Comment: One more thing... If these classes are MonoBehaviours you should probably be using Instantiate rather than calling "new WhateEver()"

Comment: Most of these classes are not MonoBehaviours as there is no "real" reason for them to be. Some of my classes are but most of these that need this information are not. My game is a turn based style 1v1. I have a Gameplay script that sets up a state machine and states to handle the flow for the user. The gameplay script is MonoBehaviours but the states and state machine code has no reason to be. I have a MyTeam and OpponentTeam class (derived from Team) that holds units (units are mono). Team classes no need for mono. I handle networking mostly at a team and state level for unit things.